# how to fetch xml data in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, reactjs, fetch

I want to fetch data from `https://virgool.io/feed/@jEbrahimi` and show data in Some list

```
fetch('https://virgool.io/feed/@jEbrahimi', { 'mode': 'no-cors' })
  .then(xml => xml.text())
  .then(xmlText => {
     var domParser = new DOMParser()
     let doc = domParser.parseFromString(xmlText, 'text/xml')
     console.log('doc: ', doc);
   })
   .catch(() => console.error('Error in fetching the website'))
```

i get nothing with this code

i want to get title text and link href in xml file

```
<title type="text"><![CDATA[استفاده از ری اکت بدون Node.js]]></title>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" 
href="https://virgool.io/@jEbrahimi/try-react-without-nodejs- 
mjscaihovuqa"></link>
```

how can i get the data and show them in the list whit `<a>` tag:

```
<div className='lastArticle'>
  <a href='https://virgool.io/@jEbrahimi/try-react-without-nodejs- 
   mjscaihovuqa'>استفاده ار ری‌اکت بدون NodeJS</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that the HTML returned from the site will be XML?  Remember, XML is far, far stricter than HTML, as browsers will ignore things like `<br>` (for example) when XML will throw an error because it expects `<br/>`

Comment: You can use libraries like xml2js to convert xml to javascript object. https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js

Comment: @freefaller thank you for your guide. is there any way to got data from that link?

Comment: @freefaller and yes it's always return a xml file

Comment: @JavadEbrahimi I think your issue would be extracting the data from the xml string returned. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, can't help with your specific question, just wanted to raise a possible issue with HTML vs XML.  Good luck

Comment: Why have you set `{ 'mode': 'no-cors' }`? That is only useful when you are making a cross-origin opaque request. Since you are trying to read the response, you can't be making an opaque request.

Comment: @philip_nunoo i can't extracting the data form that link, i looking for a way to get data

Comment: You said "i get nothing with this code" but I can't see any circumstance where that would not either give you the desired document object or error messages on the browser's Console.

Comment: Are you running this JavaScript in an HTML document hosted on `https://virgool.io/` ?

Comment: @Quentin if i remove ` { 'mode': 'no-cors' } i got `set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled` error, i add this to remove the error

Comment: @JavadEbrahimi – That message should also tell you that that will only help if an opaque request is acceptable to you. Since you need to read the response, and opaque request **isn't** acceptable to you.

Comment: @JavadEbrahimi please use the following gist and see if it helps. https://gist.github.com/Philip-Nunoo/85357e0dd09293aeecc5105922a110f1

Comment: @Quentin Thank's, virgool is website like medium and i write my article on virgool. now i want to create section on my website to show my virgool article. and this link `https://virgool.io/feed/@jEbrahimi` is my account rss link, is there any way to show article in my website?

Comment: @Quentin no i get `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://virgool.io/feed/@jEbrahimi' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error

Comment: @JavadEbrahimi — Then virgool isn't giving localhost permission to read the data. See the duplicate.

Comment: @Quentin You Are a Good Man, Thank You.